# xml parsing in golang with chardata

Tags: xml, parsing, go

https://play.golang.org/p/RioZSwO6WB ,please look into it i am not able to get the username after parsing ,program in working fine ,please look into it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your struct you're saying that the xml node is called `username` when it's actually called `userName`.

Simply replace this:

```
Username CData `xml:"username"`
```

With:

```
Username CData `xml:"userName"`
```

And it should work fine.